# Everytime I connect Organizations Account in Azure VM, VM stops working and cannot RDP anymore

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine, rdp

I'm trying to find an answer to the fact that everytime I want to connect an organizations account in the Account settings in VM, I cannot RDP anymore.

During the creation of the VM, I enable the Azure AD join extension.

Does this has to do anything about user log -in conflict.

I log in to the VM with my Admninistrator credentials.

Any idea would be highly recommended.

The VM is Windows 10 OS.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid these issues, you can use ***Windows 10 Fall Creators update (1709)*** is a separate app that provide updated version systems current and safer defense-in-depth features that prevent evolving malware and other vulnerabilities from impacting your device,

*To connect RDP, you need to add inbound port rule*

***In azure portal** -> **virtual machine** -> **Networking** ->  **Add inbound port rule** -> **Add***

[image]

**Note** : *if you are using port 3389 kindly update destination port ranges as 3389 and name as port_3389*

If you already added inbound rule and still you are facing issue refer thi[s Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-allow-access) for more information